# "Cannot read property 'classList' of null" error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a rock/paper/scissors React app. The app works fine but I just would like to add a feature.

When the user or the CPU wins, I would like to add a specific class (.bigger) to that specific  element that won.

For instance, in the following piece of code, I am trying to add the .bigger class when the user wins by selecting paper, but the app crashes.

```
 if(this.state.victory === true) {
                if(this.state.choiceName === "paper") {
                    document.getElementById("paper-box").classList.add("bigger")
                }
 }
```

I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'classList' of null". Why is that so? And how can I achieve what I want ?

Thank you very much in advance.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-smoke-7z7ej?file=/src/components/Main.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely reason (you didn't include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself) is that you haven't rendered the element with that ID at the time you are searching the DOM for it.

---

In general, when working with React, you should **not** access the DOM directly.

Your render function should be responsible for determining the output.

```
...
<span id="paper-box" className={ this.state.choiceName === "paper" ? "bigger" : "" }>
...
```